# Excel formula for dragging down a row to move across a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm wanting a `sumifs` formula such that when I drag it down a row, the `sumrang` jumps across a column (in a different tab).

For simplicity, say in cell `B2` I hav:

```
=Sumif(array, criteria, 'Sheet 1'!A:A).
```

I would like to drag this formula down such that cell B3 has

```
=Sumif(array, criteria, 'Sheet 1'!B:B).
```

I would also need this to be robust against dragging across the columns. ie. if I were to then drag across to cell C3, I'd like it to be

```
=Sumif(array2, criteria2, 'Sheet1'!B:B).
```

It seems to come down to inputting a number to produce an array, such that when this gets dragged down the rows, the number increases by 1 and thus the column of the sumrange increases
by 1. But I just can't get it to work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Use `INDEX` along with `ROW(1:1)` or something similar: `INDEX(Sheet1!1:1048576,,ROW(1:1))`

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9ge8TD845W_GdHyCB-w?e=PNseGg)/screeshot(s) refer:

**M1: sumif/offset**

```
=SUMIF(A:A,F$4,OFFSET($C:$C,0,ROWS(J$4:J4)-1,ROWS(C:C),1))
```

[image: J4: lead cell (drag right then down or simply down to J5]

*Notes: dragging J4 to right updates criteria range and criteria, but leaves sum range (A:A) unchanged. Dragging down updates only sum range (from 1 -> 2).*

---

**M2: sum/offset**

```
=SUM(IFERROR((A:A=F$4)*(OFFSET($C:$C,0,ROWS(J$9:J9)-1,ROWS(A:A),1)),))
```

[image: sum/offset lead cell: J9]

*Notes: due to 'lazy range referencing' (e.g. column A, C etc.) - iferror required within sum to mitigate instances where cells do not contain legitimate values for this fn. - see overall note section below*

---

**M3: sum/index**

```
=SUM(IFERROR(1*(A:A=F$4)*INDEX($C:$D,0,ROWS(J$15:J15)),))
```

[image: sum/index - lead cell: J15]

---

**General notes/caveats etc.**

- Ranges used in your e.g. would conflict given B2 contains initial sumif fn, with sum range immediately to left (A:A), then dragging down would attempt to sum column B (i.e. circular reference) - have updated ranges to something more purposeful accordingly). Appreciate you only provided illustrative e.g. so no sweat ☺
- Various other methods exist e.g. sumproduct, or substitute offset in
  (1) with index  (2) for same outcome; General principle: use
  reference eqn (offset/index/direct reference, etc.) s.t. column
  offset = rows
- RE: 'robust' - simply use bullets [i.e. $] to fix columns (only for sum range; other ranges assumed to be adjacent to one another given info providdd - these can be modified in similar fashion as sum range (i.e. using index/offset etc.) as req.
- This assumes sum range (given as Sheet1 A:A in your Q) identical to array / criteria range (would advise using specific range to avoid intensive calc delays - table functions, named ranges, '#' Spill references [if you have 365 Office compatable version Excel) per [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/spilled-range-operator-3dd5899f-bca2-4b9d-a172-3eae9ac22efd#:%7E:text=When%20you%27re%20dealing%20with,which%20spills%20to%20A2%3AA11.) etc.)
- (shared file link - onedrive secure - provides example of sum/filter/offset (requires Office 365) - not included above as three methods already provided (only 1 requested/req.)
- Checks substantiate veracity/accuracy of these fns as req.

Ta

---

Comment: Why do you use hight and width in your offset formulas? I tried without, and it is working as well. =SUMIF(A:A;F$4;OFFSET($C:$C;0;ROWS(J$4:J4)-1))

Comment: @JB-007 Thank you for the effort put into this solution! M1 worked perfectly well.

Comment: @Prema - interesting, when I gave it a go it gave errors - perhaps that was prior to me using iferror - I wonder whether these arguments are redundant/deprecated unofficially if what you say is true? Hmm.  But great - if you can shortent the function/formula then by all means - feel free to remove (not that anyone requires my permission lol)

Comment: (I could also say 'it's the way of a purest' - but I won't - love 'em hacks /shortcuts :)